# How do I make buttons with a for-loop

Tags: python, loops, user-interface, tkinter

It's in tkinter. The last line adds x = len(FRAME_LIST) "Buttons" into the dropdown menu. The problem is they all reference to the same frame (the last in the FRAME_LIST). How to I make it that every Button references a diffrent frame from FRAME_LIST?

```
    for F in FRAME_LIST:
        frame = ChallengePage(mainframe,self, F)
        self.frames[F] = frame
        frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
        subMenu1.add_command(label = F.id, command = lambda: self.show_frames(F))
```

EDIT:
So to be more precise, when I come across this problem i thought ok, the problem is I need to declare a local variable, so I tried this:

```
        A = F
        subMenu1.add_command(label = F.id, command = lambda: self.show_frames(A))
```

But it didnt work even though the A is declared INSIDE the loop, and redeclared in every loop, it still yields the same result.

I came now across the link: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result

where it shows the solution:

```
        subMenu1.add_command(label = F.id, command = lambda A = F: self.show_frames(A))
```

Which somehow magically works, but I don't get why it is any diffrent from my local A.

Comment: "but I don't get why it is any different from my local A" For the reason carefully explained on the same web page where that solution came from.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue when using `lambda` in loops. I usually use a `partial` instead:

```
from functools import partial

for F in FRAME_LIST:
    frame = ChallengePage(mainframe, self, F)
    self.frames[F] = frame
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    subMenu1.add_command(label=F.id, command=partial(self.show_frames, F))
```

Because: [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2295368/3642398).

To summarize: the `lambda` in your loop will remember the *name* of the variable (`F`), but not the value it points to on each iteration of the loop. By the time you are clicking the buttons and triggering the command, the name `F` points to the last value in the iteration of your for loop, and so that is what will be passed to your lambda. [Partials](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html#functools.partial) on the other hand are aware of the object that `F` points to at each iteration, and keeps track of it so that `self.show_frames()` is called with the appropriate argument.